# Searching for printer/scanner canon pixma mp230 (32bit) ubuntu 12.04 drivers and how to install

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

Searching for canon pixma mp230 (32bit) ubuntu 12.04 drivers and how to install.

Found the drivers on http://www.canon-asia.com/personal/search?languageCode=EN&filter=p&q=mp230%20linux but the install.sh doesn't seem to work. There are serveral syntax errors reported. Tried to change the problems following directions from the terminal but I didn't succeed. If anyone could help? Many thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and include the syntax errors reported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I have an answer to my own question.

Since there was a syntax error I dicided to look at the install.sh code a little closer. I opened the file in geany (lightweight ide install from repository/ubuntu softwarecenter) and tried to debug witch did not seem to work. After that I accidentally ran the code from within geany in a terminal. There were no syntax errors mentioned and the software installed, it asked me to connect the printer and answer some questions. The printer now works. By the way this method can be repeated. Why this works and I still get the same error when just running sudo ./install.sh in a terminal I do not know.

The scanner is now working too, but the only program you can use it with is gimp (going to file,create,scangear). The install.sh from the scannerdriver works with sudo ./install.sh from the terminal.

Printerdriver to download: cnijfilter-mp230series-3.80-1-deb.tar.gz

Scannerdriver to download: scangearmp-mp230series-2.00-1-deb.tar.gz

You can also use Printerdriver Canon PIXMA MP250 from Ubuntu 12.04 list

Comment: Also Printerdriver Canon pixma mp250 from list available on 12.04

Answer (score 0):

this is the scanner driver the other one didn't do it for me

http://support-au.canon.com.au/contents/AU/EN/0100469501.html