# Canon PIXIA MP 230

Tags: canon, scanner

How do I get scanner working on 12.04?
Looked at

[Searching for printer/scanner canon pixma mp230 (32bit) ubuntu 12.04 drivers and how to install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220024/searching-for-printer-scanner-canon-pixma-mp230-32bit-ubuntu-12-04-drivers-and)

downloaded scanner driver, run but nothing happened.
Any help for dummies available?

Comment: First, before trying drivers, plug the printer in and open 'printers' from 'system settings' and try adding it from there.

Answer (score 1):

found the scanner driver, it's working now 
http://support-au.canon.com.au/contents/AU/EN/0100469501.html

Answer (score 0):

Only GIMP can start ScanGear. No other application software can start ScanGear.
If GIMP is not installed, you must install the software.

hi all, found the 2 above line in the Scangear manual for linux.
looks like only GIMP can open.

i tried and it really works after several round of installing and uninstalling different mp2** drivers.

sorry..what i meant is i installed scangearmp-common_2.00-1_i386 and scangearmp-mp230series_2.00-1_i386
then start the scanning successfully through GIMP.
file -> create -> scangear MP

i tried before this on xsane and simplescan. both this doesn't work.

Comment: Please be more specific. Given as a singular answer, this does not provide enough evidence for such a bold claim. Scanning in Linux is a system, not possibly at the whim of a single application.