# installation canon pixma mp 230

Tags: drivers, canon, scanner, pixma

when installing scangear (using scangearmp-mp230series2.0-1-deb) for canon pixma mp230 it stops with

```
 Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: scangearmp-common (>= 2.00),
```

and `scanimage -L` responds

```
No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
```

Comment: could you provide the packagename you are trying to install?

Comment: scangearmp-mp230series2.0-1-deb

Comment: see the answers from http://askubuntu.com/questions/220024/searching-for-printer-scanner-canon-pixma-mp230-32bit-ubuntu-12-04-drivers-and

Comment: tried that didnt work gives mention error

Comment: I mean the other suggestion, trying to select the 250 in the ubuntu add printer dialogs

Comment: Indeed even if you install the scanner from Canon you won't be able to use simple scan but you will have to use GIMP.

Answer (score 1):

Try to download the official tar.gz from canon-asia.com (I had to choose the MP237 instead of the MP230, but that works too) , uncompress it, enter into the recent created directory, and then execute the following command:

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

It will install (in order) two packages that are inside the subdirectory 'packages', in first place the "common" package, and in second place the "mp230series" package.

Comment: An error occurred. A necessary package could not be found in the proper location when sudo ./install.sh

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is download the printer driver and scanner driver from the [Canon Asia website](http://www.canon-asia.com/personal/search?languageCode=EN&filter=p&q=mp230%20linux).

After you downloaded the packages follow the Canon installation guides:

- [Printerdriver installation](http://www.canon-asia.com/personal/search?languageCode=EN&filter=p&q=guide-pd-3.80-1_en.tar.gz)
- [Scannerdriver installation](http://www.canon-asia.com/personal/search?languageCode=EN&filter=p&q=guide-sd-2.00-1_en.tar.gz)

I recomend using the method *Installing the ScanGear by specifying the package*, since you seem to have trouble with the common package.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did. I use Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit, and have absolutely zero knowledge in Linux... or anything to do with IT actually. So for those of you who are as lost as I was a few minutes ago, and can't seem to work it through Terminal, I hope this will help.

1. I went to http://software.canon-europe.com/, navigated forward with my preferences (I live in Sweden), chose "Software (drivers and applications)" (translated it from Swedish. It should say something similar in English) and then clicked on "MP230 series IJ Printer Driver Ver. 3.80 for Linux (rpm Packagearchive)" and downloaded the file.
2. I extracted/decompressed the file.
3. I opened the extracted file and then opened "packages".
4. I right-clicked on "cnijfilter-common_3.80-1_amd64.deb" and chose "Open with Program Central for Ubuntu" (assume it says something similar in English).
5. I installed it.
6. I did the same thing with the package "cnijfilter-mp230series_3.80-1_amd64.deb".
7. Finally I simply added the printer in System Settings and voilà!

Answer (score 0):

"Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: scangearmp-common (>= 2.00), ". Did you install the "-common" file first?

If you are on AMD64, then select the respective amd64 package. First install 
"-common" file: `scangearmp-common_2.00-1_i386`, then follow by scanner file: `scangearmp-mp230series_2.00-1_i386`.

You can install either through `./install.sh` or simply click on it and let the package installer take care of it.

After installing, to use scanner I started the GIMP and access the scanner via Ffile -> Create -> Scangear MP

I tried `xsane` and `simplescan`, both did not work. On the Canon scangear manual for Linux, it says, only GIMP can start the scanner.

Here is the scanner operation manual: http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0300932901.html

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I installed these and it worked just fine after...

```
http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/5/0100004695/01/scangearmp-mp230series-2.00-1-deb.tar.gz 
http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/9/0100004659/01/cnijfilter-mp230series-3.80-1-deb.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. I downloaded [this](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/5/0100004695/01/scangearmp-mp230series-2.00-1-deb.tar.gz) and [this](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/9/0100004659/01/cnijfilter-mp230series-3.80-1-deb.tar.gz), then used the Archive Manager to extract them. Then I got to the extracted folder in Terminal and used `sudo ./install.sh` or `sh install.sh`, whatever worked. Then I ran the command `scangearmp` in Terminal to load the scanning software (sadly it doesn't seem to work with Simple Scan).

Answer (score 0):

you can install gutenprint pdd files from the ubuntu repo

```
sudo apt install printer-driver-gutenprint
```